# How to stop a coroutine running periodically in the background

Tags: android, kotlin, thread-safety, kotlin-coroutines, android-mvvm

I have created a coroutine extension function to run a coroutine in the background periodically at fixed interval.

```
/**
 * This method will receive a coroutine function block and will handle it according to the provided parameters.
 */
fun CoroutineScope.runWithCoroutineHandler(
    intervalMils: Long,
    startDelayMils: Long = 0L,
    maxDurationMils: Long = 0L,
    suspendFunctionBlock: suspend () -> Unit
): Job = launch(this.coroutineContext) {
    delay(startDelayMils)
    val startTime = System.nanoTime()
    do {
        suspendFunctionBlock()
        delay(intervalMils)
    } while ((maxDurationMils == 0L && isActive) || (isActive && ((System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1000000 < maxDurationMils)))
}
```

Now, I run a coroutine as following in a repository:

```
  fun initialize() {
        externalScope.runWithCoroutineHandler(intervalMils = INTERVAL_MILLIS) {
            process()
        }
    }
```

The issue now is, how do i correctly stop this coroutine from the background on demand?
I have tried to `cancelAndJoin()` the coroutine but how can I now refer to the specific coroutine that is running in the background?

```
fun terminate() {
    // TODO how do I cancel the running coroutine?
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you call your runWithCoroutineHandler(), it returns job and you need to keep reference of this job in order to cancel it correctly. In terminate function you can call .cancelAndJoin() function using your job reference. https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/cancel-and-join.html

Answer (score 1):

Your function does return a `Job`, all you have to do is keep that reference and cancel it (unless you're fine with cancelling `externalScope` but I assume not).

Also your `while` does not need to check `isActive` - `delay` does so internally  so your loop won't reach condition check if it gets cancelled.

Comment: Well I guess if I cancel `externalScope` it will also cancel other coroutines that are running in the background. I ll try with Job refence.

Answer (score 0):

As @Pawel said - you should keep reference on `job` you are creating.
Simplest:

```
class MyExecutor(private val externalScope: CoroutineScope){
   private var job: Job? = null
   fun initialize() {
      job = externalScope.runWithCoroutineHandler(intervalMils = INTERVAL_MILLIS) {
            process()
        }
    }
   fun terminate() {
      job?.cancelAndJoin()
   }
}
```

Comment: again, you shoud not check isActive - you cannot check it job is not active. Kotlin coroutine cancellation automatically occured on next suspension point, in your case it will be terminated before `suspendFunctionBlock()` or at `delay`